# Symbol for SAW filter - DEA142450BT-3028A1

Tags: filter, symbol, footprint, mentor-pads

I wanted to create a symbol for the SAW filter to use for my project in PADS Professional Designer, but when I try to download the part through "PartQuest" it has no symbol or footprint. In the documentation I am using there is no functional diagram given, only shapes and dimensions. I need to create a symbol for this SAW filter, so I can connect it to the HMC414 amplifier, but I don't know what outputs or inputs it has, so I don't know how to do it. Could someone help me with what this symbol should look like, or how to generate it and upload it to PADS Professional Designer?

Here is the documentation for this filter:
https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/data_sheet/rf_bpf_dea142450bt-3028a1_en.pdf

Here is a preview of the creation of the symbol in PartQuest (since I can't choose a default one, e.g. SamacSys, because one doesn't show up):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Page 2 of the datasheet gives the pinout and recommended land pattern (PCB footprint).

I don't know what schematic symbol might be appropriate - I'd probably just use a box with IN, OUT and GND pins.

If you do any amount of PC board design, you WILL have to make some of your own schematic symbols and component footprints.  Any PC design software will have ways to do this.